# present perfect or past simple for a finished action

Tags: grammar

Are these sentences correct

I feel fat. I ate too much

I feel fat because I've eaten too much

Will it be possible to write

I feel fat. I've eaten too much

What will be the difference in term of meaning

Answer (score 1):

Present perfect can be used to clarify that a specific event has happened before now.  It does not *have* to be used, and there are some instances where it should not be used.  [Read this](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html).

So:

> I feel fat.  I ate too much.

When you say this, technically you aren't implying there's a specific event where you ate too much and feel fat as a result.  You are saying generally (not specifically), in the past, you ate too much - maybe you just had a habit of overeating in the past - and are implying you feel fat as a result.

> I feel fat.  I have eaten too much.

Here, you are saying you ate too much at a specific time.  When?  We don't know - maybe you said it earlier or maybe you'll say it in the next sentence, but you're saying there's a specific event of you eating too much, and you are implying you feel fat because of it.

However, if the listener/reader knows you've just eaten and are talking about it, either from observation or context - "I ate too much" and "I have eaten too much" are not going to have much difference.

Regarding *because*: There's a strong natural connection between "I feel fat" and "I have eaten too much" - even though the listener/reader has to logically conclude you feel fat because you've eaten too much,

It's the likely path any reasonable listener/reader would take - to the point the listener/reader would feel tricked or seriously caught off guard if there was another reason you felt fat that you mention after this sentence.  To absolutely 100% remove all doubt, the *because* can be specified.

> I feel fat because I have eaten too much.

You would not be able to get away with this if the connection was less obvious.

> The leaves are <strike>green</strike> brown.  Chlorophyll is lacking.

Unless the listener/reader already knows that chlorophyll causes leaves to be green, they won't make the connection and you really should put a *because* in there.

Comment: Blaming lack of caffeine for that one.  It's fixed. :)

Comment: That's why I always read the baseball news and webcomix before I turn to ELL in the morning :)

Answer (score 0):

1a. I feel fat. 2b. I ate too much.

2) I feel fat because I have eaten too much.

there is nothing wrong with the first two sentnces 1a and 1b, but they have wrongly been joined with the subordinating conjunction "because". The sentence #2 should be:

I feel fat because I ate too much.

The sentence "I feel fat because I have eaten two much" is formed from the clauses I feel fat and I have eaten too much.

I feel fat. I ate too much vs I feel fat. I have eaten too much.

I think you can say either I ate too much or I have eaten too much.

Americans use either the present perfect or the past simple for recent actions.
However, the British use the present perfect for recent actions. See a few examples in this connection:

She has washed the dishes, look. (BE)

She washed/has washed the dishes, look. (AE).

I have already eaten my lunch. (BE)

I have already eaten my lunch or I already ate my lunch. (AE)